# Member integer changes when directly instantiated from another class

Tags: c++, class, initialization, class-constants, member-initialization

Say I have two classes, A and B. A has an integer, which it displays in the console from its constructor. It also has a member object of B. B displays an integer just like A, but it gets its integer from A when A creates it. The integer must go directly to B's constructor, since it's a const value.

So, when A passes its own integer on to B, I would expect both A and B to display the same number in the console (1). Instead, when B's constructor prints out its integer, it displays -858993460. Why is that?
*When A instantiates a B object, passing an integer along for B's const int, why does the integer change value?*

**main.cpp**

```
#include "A.h"

int main() {
A a;
std::cin.get();
return 0;
}
```

**A.h**

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include "B.h"

class A {
public:
A() :
    b(NUM_A) 
{ std::cout << "A's number: " << NUM_A << std::endl; }

private:
B b;
const int NUM_A = 1;
};
```

**B.h**

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>

class B {
public:
B (int num) : 
    NUM_B(num) 
{ std::cout << "B's int: " << NUM_B << std::endl; }

const int NUM_B;
};
```

Comment: Do not put constants in UPPERCASE that's anti-pattern, unless they are preprocessor macro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the definition of `A`, member `b` comes before member `NUM_A`. As a result, `b` gets initialized before `NUM_A`. The value you pass to `B`'s constructor is an uninitialized value.

Change the order of the members in `A`. Instead of

```
B b;
const int NUM_A = 1;
```

use

```
const int NUM_A = 1;
B b;
```

Comment: Alright, thank you. But I'm curious: if I leave b before NUM_A, why wouldn't it still work if I initialized NUM_A in the constructor right before b? And just to get it straight, the compiler knows that NUM_A exists when it instantiates b, -it simply initializes it later, right?

Comment: The order of initializing in the constructor is ignored. All objects are initialized in the order in which they are declared in the class definition.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code is that `b` is getting initialized before `NUM_A`.

```
class A {
public:
    const int NUM_A = 1;

    A() :
        b(NUM_A)
    {
        std::cout << "A's number: " << NUM_A << std::endl;
    }

private:
    const int NUM_A = 1;
    B b;    

    //B b;    
    //const int NUM_A = 1;
};
```